# XSLT Template Matching from xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml code that I need to transform into a text file. I'm struggling massively with the namespaces in XSLT. I'm used to doing Export/Record and simple default namespace matches. I have the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MultiCountryIntegrationService.Core.Entities.Dto">
    <Person>
        <Addresses>
            <Address>
                <City>London</City>
                <Country>GB</Country>
                <County>London</County>
                <CreatedDate xmlns:d5p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
                    <d5p1:DateTime>2017-02-21T11:05:08.8387752Z</d5p1:DateTime>
                    <d5p1:OffsetMinutes>0</d5p1:OffsetMinutes>
                </CreatedDate>
                <DeletedDate xmlns:d5p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" i:nil="true" />
                <EndDate xmlns:d5p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" i:nil="true" />
                <Extension i:nil="true" />
                <Id>8e5b30d0</Id>
                <ModifiedDate xmlns:d5p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" i:nil="true" />
                <Number>8</Number>
                <StartDate xmlns:d5p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
                    <d5p1:DateTime>2016-06-30T22:00:00Z</d5p1:DateTime>
                    <d5p1:OffsetMinutes>120</d5p1:OffsetMinutes>
                </StartDate>
                <Street>Somewhere</Street>
                <Type>Primary</Type>
                <ZipCode>L1 1LL</ZipCode>
            </Address>
        </Addresses>
        <PersonLocalReferences xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Addresses>
            <Address>
                <City>Birmingham</City>
                <Country>ETC...</Country>
            </Address>
        </Addresses>
        <PersonLocalReferences xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
    </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

My XSLT - As you can see I've tried several approaches, done countless hours on google and stackoverflow. If I remove the `i:` and `xmlns` from the XML I can get the stylesheet to work, but I'm not in a position to change the XML. I'm using Visual Studio 2016 to create and run the xslt. If I use `"@* | node()"` I get everything, and I only want to output certain bits of information into a text file.

If I run the xslt below, I just get the header and EOF, so it looks like the `<xsl:apply-templates select="ArrayOfPerson/Person"/>` isn't selecting the right level of data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="i">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="header" />

        <xsl:text>Person</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ArrayOfPerson/Person"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
        <xsl:text>EOF</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Person">
        <xsl:value-of select="ArrayOfPerson/Person/Addresses/Address/City"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="Person/Addresses/Address/City"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="Addresses/Address/City"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
        <xsl:text>match</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You've tagged the question xslt 2.0 and your stylesheet says version="2.0", but you say you're using Visual Studio 2016, which I think only supports 1.0. This affects whether you can use the xpath-default-namespace attribute.

Comment: If you search for "XSLT default namespace" you'll find a thousand answers to this question. ArrayOfPerson is in a namespace, but you're selecting ArrayOfPerson in no namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I didn't realise Visual Studio couldn't do v2.0 makes sense with some of the other errors I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael wrote in his comment, add `xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MultiCountryIntegrationService.Core.Entities.Dto"`
to your xsl:stylesheet tag.

Note that you must include **full** namespace.